# p:tabMenu activeIndex becomes 0 after form submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu

Both pages contains the header:

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
    <p:menuitem value="Overview" outcome="index" icon="ui-icon-star">
        <f:param name="i" value="0" />
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Demos" outcome="second" icon="ui-icon-search">
        <f:param name="i" value="1" />
    </p:menuitem>
</p:tabMenu>
```

The second page contains a form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{name}" a:placeholder="What's your name?" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" outcome="second" />
    <br/> <h:outputText value="Hello, #{name}" rendered="#{not empty name}" />
</h:form>
```

The problem is that activeIndex  becomes 0 after the form submited. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it fixed by adding a `<f:param name="i" value="1" />` to commnadButton

Answer (score 0):

I personally use a `@ViewAccessedScope` for menu backingveans from DeltaSpike for this instead of passing params around.